# Connecting ADFS to Windows Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, adfs, azure-active-directory

We are developing a multi-tenant application and would like to be listed on Azure and support Azure AD as an IdP for our customers.  However, a few customers that already have ADFS 2.0 setup didn't like the idea of sync'ing all accounts and passwords to Azure AD.  So, is there anyway that when Azure AD receives a login request, somehow, have it redirect to ADFS and let ADFS do all the magic and return a token back to Azure AD which then returns JWT (using OpenID Connect) to our application?

I know that ACS supports such scenario but we are worried that Microsoft would soon drop support for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This document details how your customers can federate their ADFS instance with Azure AD:

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn550987.aspx

Comment: This article still requires directory syncing. You cannot get pure ACS with azure AD